# FOSUserBundle : one of two fields mandatory

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle in Symfony2, and I would like the user to enter at least one phone number between the home phone number and the mobile phone number, but I can't find where to add a check for at least one field filled.

Any clues ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make yourself a class constraint. Look at Symfony's cookbook section on [custom constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html). At the bottom there is a small section on class constraint validators.

You would have a constraint like this:

```
class RegistrationPhones extends Constraint
{
    public $message = '';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'user_phones_validator';
    }
}
```

Then your validator would look like this:

```
class RegistrationPhonesValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($registration, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $homePhone = $registration->getHomePhone();
        $mobilePhone = $registration->getMobilePhone();
        if (empty($homePhone) && empty($mobilePhone)) {
            $this->context->addViolationAt('homePhone', $constraint->message, array(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, your validation.yml would have an entry like so:

```
User\MyBundle\Form\Model\Registration:
    constraints:
        - User\MyBundle\Validator\Constraints\RegistrationPhonesValidator:
            message: phones.at_least_one_must_be_set
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Nice answer. I would have suggested to create a collection of `PhoneNnumber` entities and validate the collection using a combination of [Count](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html)  (min=1) and [Collection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html) ([NotBlank](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotBlank.html) + allowMissingFields=true). This would be easier to maintain when adding more types of phone numbers for example.

Comment: @nifr you are right. I thought about that myself, but decided to give this answer, to get an idea of how to proceed in the general case where you want to make sure that 1 of 2 fields is not empty. But you are right. For phone numbers, it is easier to imagine a collection of phone numbers.